# How do I know what data type to use in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, types, tuples

I'm working through some tutorials on Python and am at a position where I am trying to decide what data type/structure to use in a certain situation.

I'm not clear on the differences between arrays, lists, dictionaries and tuples.

How do you decide which one is appropriate - my current understanding doesn't let me distinguish between them at all - they seem to be the same thing.

What are the benefits/typical use cases for each one?

Comment: "leaning towards"?  What's the alternative?  What other data structure would you consider?  Please provide some insight into what real question you have.  What causes you to think a dictionary isn't the right thing to do?

Comment: Mainly because I picked it because it had curly brackets and had a nice name. How do you decide which to use? :)

Comment: I still don't get the question.  Is there any way you can provide something more concrete or specific than "decide"?  What are you looking for?  A tutorial on design?  Algorithms?  Data Structures?  Can you update your question with some details about what choices you think you have?  Could you explain why you have doubts about dictionary?

Comment: I've rewritten the question to be more generic and hence more answerable and more understandable to other people.

Comment: Here's a hint: you're overthinking it if you're worried about which data type to use.

Comment: You've changed the question too much.  You should probably have just closed it and made a new one.

Comment: Maybe, I guess that I thought that might clutter things up.

Comment: "they seem to be the same thing"?  Can you elaborate on that.  I'm still stumped as to what you're reading that is glossing over important details.  Could you provide links or quotes or a summary in your own words that shows what's so similar (and confusing) about the descriptions you're reading?

Comment: If you think that dictionaries and lists "seem to be the same thing," you need to sit down and read the documentation a little more carefully.  It's pretty clear on why they're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples first. These are list-like things that cannot be modified. Because the contents of a tuple cannot change, you can use a tuple as a key in a dictionary. That's the most useful place for them in my opinion. For instance if you have a list like `item = ["Ford pickup", 1993, 9995]` and you want to make a little in-memory database with the prices you might try something like:

```
ikey = tuple(item[0], item[1])
idata = item[2]
db[ikey] = idata
```

Lists, seem to be like arrays or vectors in other programming languages and are usually used for the same types of things in Python. However, they are more flexible in that you can put different types of things into the same list. Generally, they are the most flexible data structure since you can put a whole list into a single list element of another list, but for real data crunching they may not be efficient enough.

```
a = [1,"fred",7.3]
b = []
b.append(1)
b[0] = "fred"
b.append(a) # now the second element of b is the whole list a
```

Dictionaries are often used a lot like lists, but now you can use any immutable thing as the index to the dictionary. However, unlike lists, dictionaries don't have a natural order and can't be sorted in place. Of course you can create your own class that incorporates a sorted list and a dictionary in order to make a dict behave like an Ordered Dictionary. There are examples on the Python Cookbook site.

```
c = {}
d = ("ford pickup",1993)
c[d] = 9995
```

Arrays are getting closer to the bit level for when you are doing heavy duty data crunching and you don't want the frills of lists or dictionaries. They are not often used outside of scientific applications. Leave these until you know for sure that you need them.

Lists and Dicts are the real workhorses of Python data storage.

Comment: I'd add that tuples correspond most directly to mathematical tuples (pairs, triples, etc.), as opposed to lists which are sequences of objects.  So use a tuple when you have a collection of things which comprise one item (e.g. x and y coordinates), and lists when they are conceptually separate items.

Answer (score 6):

How do you decide which data type to use? Easy:

You look at which are available and choose the one that does what you want. And if there isn't one, you make one.

In this case a dict is a pretty obvious solution.

Comment: +1. Your second paragraph is precisely the right answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Best type for counting elements like this is usually [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'asdhbaklfbdkabhvsdybvailybvdaklybdfklabhdvhba'
d = defaultdict(int)

for c in s:
   d[c] += 1

print d['a']   # prints 7
```

Comment: Why would a defaultdict be better than an ordinary dict?

Comment: defaultdict creates default values for any keys not already in the dict. in the case of int, the default is 0. This saves you from having to detect the first time and item is recorded in the dict.

Comment: I've modified the question quite substantially, so for new readers this answer might seem out of context. It was a good one for the original question though!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really require speed/efficiency?  Then go with a pure and simple dict.

Answer (score 0):

Personal:
**I m**ostly work with lists and dictionaries.
It seems that this satisfies most cases.

**Sometimes:**
Tuples can be helpful--if you want to pair/match elements. Besides that, I don't really use it.

**However:**
I write high-level scripts that don't need to drill down into the core "efficiency" where every byte and every memory/nanosecond matters. I don't believe most people need to drill this deep.